# Sequelize migrations not picking up model changes

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and have been reading through the documentation to get the migrations workflow, as described in this video, to work: [Sequelize Migrations](https://youtu.be/wHTBxtk8ezo?t=5m20s)

I understand that running the commands from the CLI to `model:create ...` creates the model as well as the migration file. After running `db:migrate` to have the database up-to-date, I'd like to alter the model that was just created (e.g. adding a new column) and then creating `migration:create ...` it doesn't recognize the changes to the model. It's simply the boilerplate code for writing the migration from scratch.

In the video, I can see that creating a new migration detects the changes and creates the migration file accordingly.

Was this feature removed from the new Sequelize CLI? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The video you linked is referring to a project that has been deprecated: 
https://github.com/origin1tech/sequelize-cmd

sequelize-cli is a different project and as far as I am aware does not auto generate migration files.